# Why is FileStream not writable?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a console program. I got the code to work but I want to change it into a generic function to enable using different `Stream` sources (such as `MemoryStream`).

Here's my program:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream("f:\\!temp\\marcXmlRecords.mxml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        var reader = new MarcXmlReader().Read(fs);

        foreach (var record in reader)
        {
            var leader = record.Leader;
            var controlFields = record.GetControlFields();
            var dataFields = record.GetDataFields();
            var allFields = record.GetVariableFields();

            using (var fs2 = new FileStream("f:\\!temp\\marcRecords.mrc", 
                FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                using (var writer = new MarcStreamWriter(fs2, "UTF-8"))
                {
                    var wrecord = MarcFactory.Instance.NewRecord();
                    wrecord.Leader = record.Leader;

                    foreach (var cfield in controlFields)
                    {
                        wrecord.AddVariableField(cfield);
                    }

                    foreach (var dfield in dataFields)
                    {
                        wrecord.AddVariableField(dfield);
                    }

                    foreach (var afield in allFields)
                    {
                        wrecord.AddVariableField(afield);
                    }

                    writer.Write(wrecord);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, works fine. Now let's make it more generic:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream("f:\\!temp\\marcXmlRecords.mxml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (var fs2 = new FileStream("f:\\!temp\\marcRecords.mrc", 
                FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                ConvertXmlMarcToMarc(fs, fs2);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void ConvertXmlMarcToMarc(Stream fin, Stream fout)
    {
        var reader = new MarcXmlReader().Read(fin);

        foreach (var record in reader)
        {
            var leader = record.Leader;
            var controlFields = record.GetControlFields();
            var dataFields = record.GetDataFields();
            var allFields = record.GetVariableFields();

            using (var writer = new MarcStreamWriter(fout, "UTF-8"))
            {
                var wrecord = MarcFactory.Instance.NewRecord();
                wrecord.Leader = record.Leader;

                foreach (var cfield in controlFields)
                {
                    wrecord.AddVariableField(cfield);
                }

                foreach (var dfield in dataFields)
                {
                    wrecord.AddVariableField(dfield);
                }

                foreach (var afield in allFields)
                {
                    wrecord.AddVariableField(afield);
                }

                writer.Write(wrecord);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an exception on the line: `using (var writer = new MarcStreamWriter(fs2, "UTF-8"))`:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Stream was not writable.

**Stack Trace**

> at System.IO.BinaryWriter..ctor(Stream output, Encoding encoding, Boolean leaveOpen)
>   
> at MARC4J.Net.MarcStreamWriter..ctor(Stream output, String encoding, Boolean allowOversizeRecord)
>   
> at MARC4J.Net.MarcStreamWriter..ctor(Stream output, String encoding)
>   
> at SummonImport.Program.ConvertXmlMarcToMarc(Stream fin, Stream fout) in F:!!LocalRepository\Libraries_Apps\SummonImport\trunk\release\SummonImport\SummonImport\Program.cs:line 35
>   
> at SummonImport.Program.Main(String[] args) in F:!!LocalRepository\Libraries_Apps\SummonImport\trunk\release\SummonImport\SummonImport\Program.cs:line 20
>   
> at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>   
> at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>   
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>   
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>   
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: added stack trace

Comment: any chance the file is marked as Read Only or the user you are running does not have rights to write to the file?

Comment: it is not read only, and i do have rights. I can run it multiple times the first way, but as soon as i move the using statements around, it breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example you open and close the file on each loop.

in your second example you are not reopening the file, the likelihood is that when the writer is disposed it is closing the underlying stream. The exception will be occurring on the second time through the loop.

Try moving the using statement to wrap the for loop and it should work

Comment: OK, i moved the `MarcStreamWriter` using statement to wrap the entire function and it works now. I see what you mean about closing/reopening it on every loop - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need the [FileStream constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyhc0kft(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a `FileAccess` parameter:

```
using (var fs2 = new FileStream("f:\\!temp\\marcRecords.mrc", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
```

`FileMode.OpenOrCreate` on its own isn't enough to make it writable:

> Specifies that the operating system should open a file if it exists; otherwise, a new file should be created. If the file is opened with FileAccess.Read, FileIOPermissionAccess.Read permission is required. If the file access is FileAccess.Write, FileIOPermissionAccess.Write permission is required. If the file is opened with FileAccess.ReadWrite, both FileIOPermissionAccess.Read and FileIOPermissionAccess.Write permissions are required.

Comment: i tried adding that, still get the exception.

Comment: @solidau I can't duplicate the error. Use the debugger to examine `fs2.CanWrite` before you call your function. It shows `True` for me. Maybe it's a problem in whatever your `MarcStreamWriter` constructor is doing?

Comment: CanWrite = true      hmmmmmmmm... constructor works fine if i put `using` just before

Comment: i dont expect you to go thru the trouble but FWIW it is the nuget package Marc4J.NET